# Javascript execution order issue in bundled typescript

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, bundle

I got a problem with execution order of generated javascript when bundling.
I'm getting this error when I bundle it all together.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I believe I've narrowed it down to `angular.module("app.demo").service()` being called before `angular.module("app.demo", [])` in the combined `appbundle.js`.

I've setup bundling like so. In visual studio 2013.
[image: typescript setup]

My folder structure is as follows:

[image: folder structure]

I include it like so in my index.html.

```
<script src="App/appbundle.js"></script>
```

The relevant typescript files:

**app.module.ts**

```
module App {
    "use strict";

    // Create the module and define its dependencies.
    angular.module("app", [
        // Angular modules
        "app.core",
        "app.demo",
        "app.services"
    ]);
}
```

**demo.service.ts**

```
module App.Services {
    "use strict";

    export interface IDemoService {
        getData: () => Array<string>;
    }

    class demoService implements IDemoService {
        static $inject: string[] = ["$http"];

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        }

        getData(): Array<string> {
            return ["one", "two", "three"];
        }
    }

    angular.module("app.services").service("demoService", demoService);
}
```

**services.module.ts**

```
module App.Services {
    "use strict";

    // Create the module and define its dependencies.
    angular.module("app.services", []);
}
```

As stated earlier. I believe the problem comes from the order in which the files are combined into the `appbundle.js`.

So my question is. **How do I fix this while keeping the bundling feature?**

I realize that renaming the files would change the order they're included. But that's not something I'm willing to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I fix this while keeping the bundling feature?

Use an external bundler e.g. webpack.

More : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md